# theory to practice with test plates

Tags: materials

A few minutes ago I asked a question here about a project for my raspberry that I want to achieve. After the theory, practice. But I do not know how to do it. I have 
test plates (with track) of this type:

[image]

but also the same test plates but without track.

After some experience on a test plates with track where I had to cut with a cutter the tracks so that the circuit is correct and my elements organized in a harmonious way I find this laborious and in addition the track is taken off very easily (problem of quality of test plates?)

What are the primary techniques for creating a small plug-in using a few components and test plates would you have recommendations?

What bothers me is that the same principle as for a breadboard (there is necessarily a shift in the placement of the components (visually I speak) .I am obliged to cut tracks which greatly weakens the test plates and build bridges.

**Else, is there any software that can give me a representation for a trial work of test plates, who could give me the layouts and thus tell me for example the necessary bridges to achieve but also the necessary cuts?**

Comment: How are you cutting the tracks? I don't think it should greatly weaken the 'test plates' (I know them as proto-boards or Veroboards)

Comment: what you call "test plates" are more commonly called stripboard or veroboard. You may want to look into the various other prototyping boards available, as there are some that have exactly the layout of a breadboard.

Comment: @immibis With a simple 'cutter' sorry it's the French word, maybe 'Retractable knife' ?

Comment: @Hearth, because all french vendors call this test plates. I am looking for a simpler way to create a harmonious and compact prototyping.

Comment: You may find it useful to look into the various offerings [here](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/prototyping-fabrication-products/prototype-boards-perforated/636), as stripboard is not the only option. Like I said earlier, there are some that are [exactly the same layout as a solderless breadboard](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/sparkfun-electronics/PRT-12699/1568-1289-ND/5762439).

Comment: @Heart Thank you very much, this perfectly answers my question. Tracks ready! perfect.

Comment: @Hearth, can you make a response please. I want to put this answer as correct. The answer is simply there are stripboard (same name ?) with tracks already ready (I do not know how to explain it better) or with individual hole connectable maybe ?, oh and do you known a software for simulate this please ?

Comment: @Ephemeral Done. I unfortunately can't answer the bit asking about software, as though I know software exists, I don't know any specific examples.

Comment: @Heart No problem thank you anyway.

Comment: having solved the 8-queens chess problem in LISP using search, you certainly can do the same for this 2_d problem.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf Thank you for this discovery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though there is software for stripboard, and there are cases when stripboard is the better option, it sounds like what you want is more along the lines of one of [these](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/sparkfun-electronics/PRT-12699/1568-1289-ND/5762439) or [similar](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/sparkfun-electronics/PRT-12070/1568-1082-ND/5230951) [products](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/chip-quik-inc/SBB136/SBB136-ND/7035054). The linked boards have exactly the same arrangement of pads as a standard breadboard, but you can also get various other arrangements, such as [this one](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/chip-quik-inc/SBB1605-1/SBB1605-1-ND/5978253) with extra power rails across the board, or [this one](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/vector-electronics/8023/V2040-ND/1754474) for extremely large projects, or quite a lot of other options. [Take a look.](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/prototyping-fabrication-products/prototype-boards-perforated/636)

Comment: thank you very much.

Comment: Sorry I answered a little quickly, it seems that your examples of products correspond to a 'breadboard', I do not want this type of arrangement because I want a harmonious alignment of my components. I would need a plates between those that sell with tracks (material + hole) and those sold without tracks (just the hole) to not have to cut the tracks manually. Basically, I need a plates with INDIVIDUAL hole and having a little material to weld.

Comment: Like [this one](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/dfrobot/FIT0203/1738-1001-ND/6588423) for example? Just try browsing around that last link I sent, you'll find plenty of options. I'm not really sure what you mean by "harmonious alignment", though.

Comment: exactly ! thank you very much for time !

Comment: Sorry it's me again :) How do I know if, for example, this product  https://www.amazon.fr/dp/B073W78G8J/ref=sspa_dk_detail_1?psc=1 has tracks inside the PCB (what I do not want I recall, I want each hole to be individual and weldable)? Thank you